# Which result should I choose if the knn result returns the same quantity

Tags: algorithm, knn

I have run a KNN=5, and the result contains:

- 2: upgrade
- 2: remains
- 1: Downgrade

I got 2 "upgrade" & 2 "remains".
How do I decide on the expected results?
Upgrade or remain?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the help section on how to ask and then edit your question, as this will help the community better understand your specific issue and provide you with a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Consider the average distances to break ties.

Comment: Do u mean the shortest average distance of the 2 label?